How to change content of .eml email file with Base64 encoded text?
I have a .eml email file which I want to send. I open the file Outlook but it contains some unnecessary sentences which I want to delete.
I tried to open the .eml file in notepad and locate the content of the email which is decoded in Base64 Utf-8. I decoded it with a online tool and changed the text I wanted. When I encoded that text back to Base64 Utf-8, I pasted it where the original text was in the .eml file.
The problem is that when I open the edited file in Outlook, I get to see the same original email, not containing the edited content. Even when I deleted the the whole content in notepad I still see the same email. Only when I delete literally all the text in the file it gives a error when opening it in Outlook.
Can someone help me to fix this and be able to change the content? The funny thing is that changing the subject through notepad works but this is not decoded.
Does someone maybe have a Python script for this which makes it easier?

Make sure to update both plain text and html parts.
